# Long string concatenation in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am working in ASP.net application with SQL Server 2008 database. I know in .net when we need to do any long string concatenation we should use `StringBuilder` instead of using "+" or "&" operator.
EX.

```
string myString = "SELECT column1,"
 + " column2,"
 + " column3,"
 + " column4,"
 + " column5,"
 + " column6,"
 + " FROM table1 t1"
 + " JOIN table2 t2"
 + " ON t1.column1 = t2.column1";
```

I want to know is this also applicable in SQL Server that this type of string concatenation we should avoid there also? if yes then what is the right way to concatenate the long string in SQL Server.

Comment: Personally, I use this a fair amount for doing dynamic SQL, and it's never caused any performance issues yet.  I don't think (maybe someone can correct me on this if i'm not right) that strings in SQL are immutable like they are in the .net languages (which is the main issue and why you're generally taught not to create large blocks of text as strings).

Comment: What do you consider "long"? And what are you concatenating? Just Dynamic SQL strings?

Comment: FYI, there is no string concatenation occurring in the code you posted.  That will be stored as a single string at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in [T-SQL Concat method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) which is the equivalent of building a string with the string builder.

According to the documentation, this is **only available in SQL Server 2012 or 2014** so in your case, you would need to stick to the `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason not to use the +

```
DECLARE  @myString VARCHAR(4000) = 'SELECT column1,'
 + ' column2,'
 + ' column3,'
 + ' column4,'
 + ' column5,'
 + ' column6,'
 + ' FROM table1 t1'
 + ' JOIN table2 t2'
 + ' ON t1.column1 = t2.column1';
```

Answer (score -1):

In my limited experience, I've found that almost every time I think I should concatenate data in a SQL query, I find later that I should have queried it as is, then handled string manipulation in C# land. Every time you concatenate two results from the database, you increase the chances of running into an edge case.

Consider, for example, an address. My database stores address with the following columns:

- Addr1
- Addr2
- City
- StateCd
- ZipCd
- ZipSuf
- CntryCd

At first, it seems logical to have Addr1 and Addr2 each on a separate line, followed by City, StateCd, ZipCd-ZipSuf, CtryCd. In reality, this leads to a lot of conditional formatting in SQL if Addr2 or ZipSuf are null.